# Attach file in Angular JS page using Selenium Python Javascript executor

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, selenium

I need to upload a file to a webpage using selenium python Javascript executor. 
The webpage code looks like..

```
<label for="file81">
<i class="mdi mdi-attachment" aria-hidden="true"/>
<span class="sr-only">Attach files to this message</span>
</label>
<input id="file81" class="sr-only ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" type="file" multiple="" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)" ng-model="messageAttachment"/
```

Can anbody tell me how to upload file in this using javascript executor. Thanks

Comment: Could we know, why do you want to use `javascript executor` here?? While it can be possible as `driver.find_element_by_id("file81").send_keys("path/to/file")`

Comment: this is not working. I get error like no such element. Please provide me a solution for this

Comment: Is this element id `file81` fixed or dynamically generated?

Comment: If this element dynamically generated try using other locator as `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[ng-model='messageAttachment']").send_keys("path/to/file"‌​)`

Comment: Send keys itself wont work, because there is no textbox in webpage, there is a attachment button which when i click opens a window based pop up.

Comment: Did you tried?? Or just saying.. it's a input file element and here sendKeys should work, need to try first then let me know

Comment: I did try with whatever u have posted.. Thats y i am searching for an alternative solution.

Comment: the test is passing.. but the file is not getting uploaded. this is what i meant to say. if u have any alternative solution please come forward